# Python 3 No module named '_ssl'

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, pyopenssl

**The Problem**

While I run you python3 application, it shows

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'
```

---

**What I've tried**

install the dependencies

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

I also edited the **setup.py** file and recomplie python3

```
# Detect SSL support for the socket module (via _ssl)
search_for_ssl_incs_in = [
                          '/usr/local/ssl/include',
                          '/usr/local/include/openssl', #I've added this line
                          '/usr/contrib/ssl/include/'
                         ]
```

I've complied the openssl with the path configuration

```
#tar -xzvf openssl-***.tar.gz

#./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl

#make & make install
```

---

CentOS 7

Python 3.6

Comment: Can you try compiling with --with-ssl option?

Comment: the --with-ssl is out of date

Comment: @Lanston: I am facing the same issue...how had you fixed it?

Comment: @Lanston i am facing the same issue please help me how you solved it

Answer (score 6):

I found some solution:

if you use centos,try:

## s1

```
yum install openssl-devel -y
```

then when you compile, append --with-ssl,just like this

```
./configure prefix=/usr/local/share/python3 --with-ssl
```

### s2

-- install depend library, make share compile is fluent

```
yum install -y zlib zlib-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel libffi libffi-devel gcc gcc-c++

(ubuntu)sudo apt-get install libz-dev

wget --no-check-certificate http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1
./config --prefix=$HOME/openssl shared zlib
make && make install
```

-- configure shared ld library path so that compile can find it

```
echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/openssl/lib" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

(zsh user has some different with .zsh_profile)
-- compile with openssl path

```
 ./configure prefix=/usr/local/share/python3 --with-openssl=$HOME/openssl
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, I installed python from source and didn't enabled ssl option while compiling. So I find the solution in the following [article](https://techglimpse.com/install-python-openssl-support-tutorial). You need to find `ssl` section `Modules/Setup.dist` and uncomment that section. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

For those who coming here having Ubuntu: try `apt install libssl-dev`